# Phonegap user login

Tags: 7, services

I am trying to login from a PhoneGap application. For that purpose, I've got the below code:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://dev-7.webcinizim.com/services/system/connect.json',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert('Login successful');
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('err');
        }
    });
});
```

I also followed [this tutorial](http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile) and created a service. I am always getting **Login successful** even if I feed wrong credentials on purpose.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend utilizing [jDrupal](http://github.com/easystreet3/jDrupal) or [DrupalGap](http://drupalgap.org), they'll make your life so much easier if you're building a mobile application for Drupal with PhoneGap. Otherwise, to login via Services do a **POST** to **?q=[my-endpoint]/user/login.json** and set the header **Content-type** to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and send along the following data.

```
{
  username: 'bob',
  password: 'secret'
}
```

Note, you *may* have to instead append the credentials to the path that you are POSTing to, and not send along a JSON object, for example:

```
?q=[my-endpoint]/user/login.json&username=bob&password=secret
```

The code that you have is just doing a System Connect, which returns information about the current session, and whether or not the user is logged in, it does *not* have anything to do with actually logging in.

Comment: Hey @tyler, been searching for you in #drupal*, glad to have found you here :) Anyway, if I just want to make a mobile application for an already existing Drupal site, do I still use jDrupal or DrupalGap?

Comment: Hello, I am available as `frankenstein` on IRC. I'd recommend starting with DrupalGap (which is dependant on jDrupal) and is an app development kit. Whereas jDrupal is just a JavaScript library for communicating with D6-D8 websites via a RESTful API (Services module in D6/7, REST Core in D8) and can be used in any hybrid environment (html/css/js).

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. When your success callback function is called, it only means ***it was successful POSTing the data*** to your endpoint `http://dev-7.webcinizim.com/services/system/connect.json`, not that you were successful logging in.

You need to add an argument to your success callback (i.e. `success: function(data) {`) and process that data to see whether login was successful.

Comment: And check for what?

Comment: The user object. See the tutorial you linked to, it demonstrates taking action on the `data` argument.